# how to handle multiple requests in django at same time

Tags: django

if multiple users logs in and query for something at the same time, then how can i recognize which user queried for which thing.

i tried to make a group chat system. the idea is just to make a wall on which all users will post but the problem is how can i know which user requested to post if there r multiple users at same time.

my views.py-

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        u = user.objects.get(username = post['username'])
        if post['password'] == u.password:
            request.session['username'] = u.username
            return redirect('wall')
    else:
            return render(request, 'wall/login_page.html')

 def wall(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'logout' in post:
            del request.session['username']
            return redirect('home')
        elif 'post' in post:
            posted_by = request.session.get('username', '')
            post_content = post['post_text']
            post_id = posted_by+''+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y")
            p = user_post(posted_by = posted_by, post_content = post_content, post_id = post_id)
            p.save()
            return redirect('wall')
    else:
        if 'username' in request.session:
            posts = user_post.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'wall/wall_page.html', {'posts': posts}) 
        else:
            return redirect('error')
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`request` has a `user` attribute that indicates which user made the request (which may be the `AnonymousUser` if you don't require logins).

Comment: so how can i recognize those users..??

Comment: @aquaman: Well, in that case, you will, I suppose, have to work with sessions to track users. But it's a lot easier if you use the Django auth app.